# In Skype, how can I hang up from a group call that I started without ending the call for everyone else?

Tags: skype, telecommunication

I often will start a group call (which makes me the "creator" of the call) but need to leave before others on the call wrap up. How can I hang up from my end while allowing the remaining users to continue on the call?

I have tried promoting other people on the call to the "master" role using the command `/setrole [Skype Name] MASTER` (detailed at [What are chat commands and roles?](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA10042/What-are-chat-commands-and-roles)), but when I hang up, it still ends the call for them.

Comment: That sounds quite impossible as the standard conference call config. If the presenter/host close the conference, this will disconnect everybody.

Comment: +1 - I, too, would like to make this happen. I tend to be the group call initiator, and also the first to leave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bad news is you can't since your PC is routing the call.

As some sort of workaround i installed a Skype on a little Homeserver of mine so i can call myself prior to the conference call and then invite the other participants, that way the server is the actual host and i can leave anytime while the server still maintains the conference.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that Skype now supports just this and it only (it's the original behavior that apparently is not supported anymore).

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this?  In what version did it change?

Comment: @G-Man I haven't been keeping track of it but I am certain you can't find any phone Skype with the old behavior these days. They are all banned (they force one to update). I don't know if this answer helps though, because I am not sure about the purpose/focus of your question.

Comment: My point is that your answer reads as a statement of your personal knowledge / experience / observation.  If you could provide a link to a page at microsoft.com or skype.com confirming your statement, that would make your answer more authoritative.   Related: [Can an answer be backed up only by personal experience?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12814/354511)

Comment: This sounds like it could possibly be a consequence of [Skype's move from peer-to-peer to cloud architecture](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12381/what-does-it-mean-that-skype-is-moving-from-peer-to-peer-to-the-cloud).